# BasicConfigurator doesn't log stack traces by default in JUnit Tests

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

In running some **JUnit tests** I start with the following to set up **Log4J**:

`BasicConfigurator.configure()`

I'm then calling the following via **Commons Logging**:

`LogFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).fatal(exception)`

This doesn't print stack traces though (only the exception message).

I need to know what steps are necessary to print stack traces via the simplified logging setup used in JUnit tests? I would prefer not to have to fully configure Log4J just for JUnit tests, but if I must, let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing to do with the logger configurations.

Read the javadoc for the [`fatal(Object)`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#fatal%28java.lang.Object%29) method.  It says:

> "WARNING Note that passing a Throwable to this method will print the name of the Throwable but no stack trace. To print a stack trace use the fatal(Object, Throwable) form instead."

If you want the logs to include a stacktrace, you must use the 2 argument version of the method.  This applies to the corresponding methods for other log levels as well.

Comment: OMG! Why in the world would they do something as unintuitive as that?? You are a master of detail, and officially my favorite person of the day! Thank you!